# group table in terms of 2 column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I've tried to figure out how could I group my table according to my 2 column.
For example,when I write:

```
Select * 
from table
GroupBy hotelName
```

It group my table according to hotelID.However,I want to group it in terms of both hotelName and hotelID. I mean  if 2 row have same hotelID and hotelName are same, then I want to group it in a same group.Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the remaining data that you have? If the other columns are not possible to aggregate, using GROUP BY both columns will not return what you want. Consider showing some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY hotelID, hotelName
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a comma.

```
GROUP BY hotelID, hotelName
```